# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to mi clase

Tags: java, android, gson

Estoy haciendo una aplicación android y tengo un problema a la hora de tomar unos datos que me retorna un WebService y quiero meter estos datos a room pero me retorna el error del titulo.

Este es el codigo:

```
               List<User> r = (List<User>)Res.getMsg();


                registrodb.deleteAll();
                userdb.deleteAll();
                userdb.insert(r.get(0));
```

Este es el error:

```
 com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.edgemedicaloficial.Model.mRegistro.User
```

Nota: La clase User tiene bien las variables porque tambien la ocupo para consumir otro servicio que retorna lo mismo

Esto es lo que retorna el servicio que si funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto retorna el que no funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Retorna 0 en algunos porque el segundo es un login con facebook y esos datos no se llenan)

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacer `List<User> r = new ArrayList()` y `r.addAll(Res.getMsg());` ?, ¿Qué es lo que te retorna `Res.getMsg()`?

Comment: Msg: [{nombres=null, apellidos=null, birthdate=null, telefono=null, email=test@gmail.com, pais=United States, token=123456789, username=Test, id_paciente=64}]

Comment: Si no especificas los tipos de datos que retorno Res y la estructura de los objectos, será complicado date una solución.

Comment: El error es muy raro porque `List<User> r = (List<User>)Res.getMsg();` según las imagen debería se un List de LinkedTreeMap, pero por el mensaje de error pareciera un LinkedTreeMap, si puedes colocar las estructuras de los objetos de Msg y Res, ademas no coloques imágenes con texto, porque obliga a escribir a mano lo que muestras para realizar pruebas lo cual no es de buen gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu objeto `Res.getMsg()` es algo de tipo `LinkedTreeMap<Integer, User> msg` entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
List<User> r = new ArrayList();

Res.getMsg().forEach((k, v) -> {
    User user = new User();
    user.setNombres(v.getNombres());
    user.setApellidos(v.getApellidos());
    user.setBirthdate(v.getBirthdate());
    //...
    r.add(user);
});
```

Comment: No amigo, no me funciono, tal vez mi ultima actualización a la pegunta te es útil

Comment: Creo que Fernando tiene un buen punto de solución, pero sospecho que Res.getMsg() debería de ser LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> pero `Res` oculta el TreeMap en la propiedad Msg tras Object, puede que con un cast funcione ` ((LinkedTreeMap) Res.getMsg()).forEach`.